# Programmatically click on home button and turn off screen in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, plugins

How can access programmatically home and power buttons ,I know that that turning screen off is only accessed by system apps in android , but what about moving to home screen ,can it accessed programmatically from flutter and if not are there any plugins that can do that action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible to turn off the screen in Flutter, however you can perform system actions:

Use this library:

```
system_shortcuts: ^1.0.0
```

Import it like this:

```
import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';
```

And then you can call:

```
await SystemShortcuts.home();
```

Please note however that this requires your function in which you call it to be async